# Expectation of a Brownian process $W_s$ times its exponential

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

how do you get the Expectation of a Brownian process $W_s$ times the exponential of it? Where 0$\le$s$\lt$t and $W_0$=0?

I know that $E[e^{W_s-W_t}]$ is $\frac 12$$e^{(t-s)}$

So what is $E[W_se^{W_s-W_t}]$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sigma(W_t-W_s)$ and $\sigma(W_u:u\leq s)$ are independent and that $W_s$ is measurable w.r.t. the latter.